# what characters are matched by '\w' in grep search?

Tags: unicode, grep

Is there any way to know with certainty whether a particular Unicode point is matched or isn't by '\w' (apart from running searches on all the characters I want to know about)? It's straightforward in English but less so in a language like Khmer, which has characters used in words that apparently don't match '\w'. Specifically, is there any way to know by looking at a character's official Unicode description?

Comment: see also: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

standard grep may not handle unicode, GNU grep with `-P` or `--perl-regexp` option.

```
grep -P '\p{L}'
```

otherwise `\w` matches `[0-9A-Za-z_]`.